# Jquery: Property disable enable by if else OR directly put condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have two choices:

```
if ($("#drpYear").val() == "0") {
   $("#drpMake").prop("disabled", true);
}
else {
   $("#drpMake").prop("disabled", false);
}
```

OR

```
$("#drpMake").prop("disabled",$("#drpYear").val() == "0" );
```

I know both would do same thing, which one is better, is 2nd option better in performance? Which one should be used?

Comment: They both have to perform the same comparison at some stage, I highly doubt there is a worthwhile performance gain anywhere. I would go with the first solution for readability

Comment: First one is more readable in my eyes. If you wanna go with the second example, go with something like `var isValZero = $("#drpYear").val() == "0"` and `$("#drpMake").prop("disabled", isValZero );` to have speaking names for variables

Answer (score 2):

Take a look in this performance test, as @Norsk said, the difference is minimal but the test shows the first one performs better, and is more readable.

Test: [JsPerf](https://jsperf.com/jqueryperfomanceif/1)

Result for my settings:
[image]

*Note*: The difference is so small that it can show different results.